# To show $\Lambda_f(R)$ is finite if and only if $f$ is bounded, where $f$ is monotone increasing

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let  $f$ is monotone increasing

To show $\Lambda_f(R)$ is finite if and only if f is bounded, where $\Lambda_f$ is Lebesgue-Stieltjes outer measure

($\Leftarrow$) I have proved it.

But how to approach ($\Rightarrow$) ? Since $f$ is not right continuous so we can't use $\Lambda_f((a,b])=f(b)-f(a)$

Comment: Sir, could you tell me how to prove $(\Leftarrow)$? Thank you.

Comment: Consider, (-n,n] . By definition of $\Lambda$, we have $\Lambda_f(-n,n]\leq f(n)-f(-n)$ and $\Lambda_f$ is already an outer measure, hence by continuity we done.

Comment: And I found the the other direction will be false if $f$ is not right continuous

Comment: Does that comment mean you have solved your problem, Zoe? If so, let me encourage you to write it up and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is right continuous , then for such interval $(a,b]$ we have $$\Lambda_f(a,b]=f(b)-f(a)$$
And consider the special interval, we have $$\Lambda_f(-n,n]=f(n)-f(-n) $$
And the both side direction will be done by passing $n\rightarrow\infty$ and use the continuity of outer measure.

Now, if the problem does not assume $f$ is right continuous. Then there exists a counterexample for ($\Rightarrow$)

Define $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq 1$ and $f(x)=n$ if $x\in (n,n+1]$, where $n\in N$

Consider $R=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n\in N}(n,n+1]$, then since the union is disjoint $$\Lambda_f(R)=\displaystyle\sum_{n\in Z} \Lambda_f (n,n+1]$$

Observe that $$ \Lambda_f (n,n+1] =0$$ for $n\in Z$ and $n<1$

Hence, we focus on $n\geq 1$

Consider $(\alpha, n+1]\subseteq (n,n+1]$
Then $$0\leq \Lambda_f(\alpha,n+1]\leq f(n+1)-f(\alpha)=0$$. Since $f$ is constant on$(n,n+1]$

This is true for any $\alpha$ with $n<\alpha\leq <n+1$. Hence,
$$\Lambda_f(n,n+1] =\displaystyle\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow n} \Lambda_f(\alpha,n+1] =0$$

Hence, $$\Lambda_f(R)=\displaystyle\sum_{n\in Z} \Lambda_f (n,n+1] =0$$

But $f$ is unbounded.